# Scraping from dropdown option value Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried scraping data from the web with input dropdown with BeautifulSoup

this is value drop down

```
<selected name="try">
<option value="G1">1</option>
<option value="G2">2</option>
</selected>
```

And I try like this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
soup['selected'] = 'G1'
data = soup.findAll("table", {"style": "font-size:14px"})
print(data)
```

It will get data with `<table>` tag each submit dropdown

but it only appears `<table>` for the main page, how do I get data  from each dropdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still keep using `findAll()` and `find()` to finish your job.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table style="font-size:14px">
<selected name="try">
<option value="G1">1</option>
<option value="G2">2</option>
</selected>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

option = soup.find("selected",{"name":"try"}).findAll("option")
option_ = soup.find("table", {"style": "font-size:14px"}).findAll("option")
print(option)
print(option_)
#[<option value="G1">1</option>, <option value="G2">2</option>]
#[<option value="G1">1</option>, <option value="G2">2</option>]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS selector

```
soup.select('option[value]')
```

The `[]` is an attribute selector. This looks for `option` tag elements with `value` attribute. If there is a parent class/id that could be used that would be helpful in case there are more drop downs available on the page.

```
items = soup.select('option[value]')
values = [item.get('value') for item in items]
textValues = [item.text for item in items]
```

With parent `name` attribute to limit to one dropdown (hopefully - you need to test and see if something further is required to sufficiently limit). Used with [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator):

```
items = soup.select('[name=try] option[value]')
```

Comment: soup.select('option[G1]') like this?

Comment: Is there a parent id/class for the drop down?

Comment: <selected name="try"> @QHarr

Comment: I mean can i get table from G1 and G2? based on user input

i already have dropdown list
<selected name=try>
<option value="G1">1</option>
<option value="G2">2</option>

Comment: The above will extract the text in those drop downs for each option as well as the values of the value attribute.

Comment: If there is a table somewhere then you need to show more HTML / share the URL if possible.

Comment: its only get option value text, not table tag

Comment: There is no table tag in the html you have shown. Please update to include the full relevant HTML.

Comment: Still no table tag. You have a selected tag and option tag elements.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_value2 This example, suppose that the fruit is the <table> tag

Comment: There is no _table_ tag. That is soup.select('#mySelect option[value]') My answer above does the same thing. Just, as you no id specified for the parent I have used the name attribute you gave. It has a parent _select_ tag as is appropriate for a selectable dropdown list.