# I wish to scrape a site with buttons, drop down list and search

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

'''
I had a code for the webpage but on a different link. But I am unable to **scrape** this one due to the drop-down tabs. Is there a universal way to scrape a web page with this sort of structure or do we have to look at the structure and scrape?
here is the link I wish to scrape: https://www.moneycontrol.com/markets/fno-market-snapshot

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
r=requests.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/')

#We want to view the data in text format
data=r.text

#we can check some part of this html data
print(data[:1000])

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "bl_12"})
values=[]
for link in mydivs:
    value=link.get('href')
    values.append(value)


values= [ link.get('href') for link in mydivs]
values[0:5]
#create a temp Df
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)
stock_data = pd.DataFrame({'LINK': values})

print(stock_data.shape)
stock_data.head(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

No not really. Web crawlers and scrapers can click through link permutations or **scrape** data available in the page, but when you have complex UI making additional calls there's really no general way to do this easily. You would need to iterate through the UI for what you want to **scrape** or hook into their APIs if they allow that.

Comment: Thanks fr your comment!
any hint how can i do this >??

Comment: Seems like there are some ways to manipulate dropdowns with the library you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459163/scraping-from-dropdown-option-value-python-beautifulsoup