# How to get data scraped after selecting options (slot) that loads more data upon selection in beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Feel free to change the title if that seems inappropriate.
Link: https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/search/search.aspx?leftNavId=11238
**I'm trying access the school data from the above link. I cannot proceed without actually selecting the options.**

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$orgtype" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_orgtype">
            <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="5,12">Public School District</option>
            <option value="6,13">Public School</option>
            <option value="26,25">Alternative Education</option>
            <option value="13">Charter Public School</option>
            <option value="3">Collaborative</option>
            <option value="4">Collaborative Programs</option>
            <option value="EPPP">Educator Preparation Program Provider (EPPP)</option>
            <option value="11">Private Schools</option>
            <option value="1">Approved Special Education Agency</option>
            <option value="2">Approved Special Education School</option>
            <option value="USES">Unapproved Special Education School</option>
            <option value="95">Approved Special Education Programs</option>
            <option value="VOC">Ch. 74 Career/Voc Tech Education</option>
            <option value="INO">Innovation Schools and Academies</option>
            <option value="TISD">Title I Status – District</option>
            <option value="TISS">Title I Status – School</option>
            <option value="51">Tribal Education Agency</option>
        </select>
```

The get's loaded within this block: `https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/search/search.aspx?leftNavId=11238` from a javascript file dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_orgtypeReq"));
//]]>
</script>
```

Also, the `request method` is `POST` for the URL.

I believe it is being loaded from an API and I'm currently actively looking for the same.
This is where I make selections. With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459163/scraping-from-dropdown-option-value-python-beautifulsoup) answer, I believe I can get the data loaded from these options i.e., the 'names'.
Now the question is, how do I fetch the actual data that gets loaded after I click the 'Get Results' after making the selection? Suggestions, tips are welcome.

If selenium is the only way, with headless being selected, can it make selections? A simple yes / no would be enough for this as I haven't played with that option much.

Many thanks.

Edit1:

```
def data_fetch(url):
    soup = url_parser(url)
    print(soup.find('span', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSearchResults'}))
    print(soup.find('select', {'name': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$orgtype'}))
    print(soup.find('div', {'id': 'innerWrapper'}).find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})[-1])  # this returns you the javascript code where the data get's loaded from.
```

In the above code, print statement returns nothing within the span as the data isn't loaded. the second print statement returns me the list of options that is mentioned above. Screenshot attached [here]([image: the resultant output from the above snippet code]).
The last print statement's output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSearchResults");
try{
    parent.scroll(0, selectedElement.offsetTop);
}
catch(err){}
</script>
```

Many trials and errors have been done to proceed further but in vain as I've no idea about how to select an option and get results from it.

Edit2:

The website allows a user to load more options i.e., the school types. I want to select and get results from each of them in order to scrape data.

Comment: What exactly is your issue and where's your [mre]?

Comment: Since data is generated using js one way to get it is to use selenium, also with it you can select the options you need.

Comment: For that to be done with selenium. I'm supposed to import ui.select package from selenium to make selections from the drop down. am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the possible options for choosing the type of organization using selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# disable chromedriver log message in cmd
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])

service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/search/search.aspx?leftNavId=11238")
```

1. Using "Select" to get all options

```py
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "select"))

for i in range(1, len(select.options)):
    select.select_by_index(i)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button3").click()
    # here you get the data you need for examlle names of all organizations 
    names = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="lg"]')
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[selected="selected"]').text)
    print([mail.text for mail in names][:5])

    # update "select" to avoid exception "StaleElementReferenceException"
    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "select"))

driver.quit()
```

2. Using the value of the "value" attribute to get the type of all organizations

```py
org_type_web_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_orgtype option")[1:]
org_type_values = [org.get_attribute('value') for org in org_type_web_elements]

for org_type in org_type_values:
    driver.get(f'https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/search/search_link.aspx?orgType={org_type}&runOrgSearch=Y&leftNavId=11238')
    # here you get the data you need for examlle names of all organizations 
    names = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="lg"]')
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[selected="selected"]').text)
    print([mail.text for mail in names][:5])

driver.quit()
```

Both 1 and 2 do the same thing

Output:

```
Public School District
['1. Abby Kelley Foster Charter Public (District) (04450000)', '2. Abington (00010000)', '3. Academy Of the Pacific Rim Charter Public (District) (04120000)', '4. Acton (non-op) (00020000)', '5. Acton-Boxborough (06000000)']
Public School
['1. Abby Kelley Foster Charter Public (District): Abby Kelley Foster Charter Public School (04450105)', '2. Abington: Abington Early Education Program (00010001)', '3. Abington: Abington High (00010505)', '4. Abington: Abington Middle School (00010405)', '5. Abington: Beaver Brook Elementary (00010020)']
Alternative Education
['1. ABCD University High School (00351001)', '2. ABE Program @ Lincoln School (01601003)', '3. ALPHA Afternoon Program (01811001)', '4. Academic Center for Transitions (ACT) (03481002)', '5. Advocacy Program (01861001)']
Charter Public School
['1. Abby Kelley Foster Charter Public (District): Abby Kelley Foster Charter Public School (04450105)', '2. Academy Of the Pacific Rim Charter Public (District): Academy Of the Pacific Rim Charter Public School (04120530)', '3. Advanced Math and Science Academy Charter (District): Advanced Math and Science Academy Charter School (04300305)', '4. Alma del Mar Charter School (District): Alma del Mar Charter School (04090205)', 
'5. Argosy Collegiate Charter School (District): Argosy Collegiate Charter School (35090305)']
```

Comment: I don't use chrome. Instead, I use Brave and it crashes often no reason with no given errors. I'll fix that and revert you back with that in the mean time.

Comment: @theycallmepix To use brave just add `options.binary_location = 'path/to/your/brave.exe'` You can see the path by typing in the address bar of the browser: `brave://version/`. I tested and it works fine in both normal and headless mode

Comment: Yes, I had done that before when I was doing some other project and I applied the same to this as well. For some reason tho, even before the website loads, webdriver closes on itself. I cannot debug that until this saturday due to other work. But that's another story.

Comment: Have you tried updating the webdriver? I tested this on Brave `1.44.112 Chromium: 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and `ChromeDriver 106.0.5249.61`

Comment: Yea, I assume that's because I use nightly version of Brave which is usually unstable...